# Pass @StateObject argument to View's default initializer using weak reference

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

## Question

I have the following ObservableObject and SwiftUI view.

```swift
class ExampleState: ObservableObject {}

struct ExampleView: View {
    @StateObject var state = ExampleState()

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

And I want to pass state to the view from a UIKit view.

```swift
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    var state = ExampleState()
    func test() -> some View {
        ExampleView(state: state) // A compile error occurs on this line
    }
}
```

But I got compile error on initializer calling. And the error message says "Reference to property 'state' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit"

First, I do not understand why this is closure.

Second, when I followed the error message and put `self`, a memory leak occurred. So could you tell me if I can make it weak reference.

## Environment

- iOS 16
- Xcode 14.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *weak reference* is `@ObservedObject`

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state : ExampleState

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

- Use `@StateObject` if the view **owns** the object.
- Use `@ObservedObject` if the object is passed from another view or class.

But creating a `SwiftUI` view inside an `UIViewController` makes no sense. Interoperability between `UIKit` and `SwiftUI` must be performed with `UIHostingView/UIHostingController` and `UIViewRepresentable`